# Performing knn and lof on a large dataset with a million rows to detect outliers in R

Tags: r, knn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I want to calculate the k-nearest neighbors distance and the local outlier factor, which are used to construct continuous anomaly scores for each data point.

I use the following code:

```
library(FNN)
knn <- get.knn(as.matrix(data), k = 5)

# to build kNN score for each point,we need to take the average value in each row of the distance matrix nn.dist
data$knn_scores <- rowMeans(knn$nn.dist)

# similarly I compute lof scores
library(dbscan)
data$lof_scores <- lof(as.matrix(data), k = 5)
```

The result is as follows:

```
select(data,knn_scores,lof_scores)

# knn_scores lof_scores
# <dbl>      <dbl>
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1           
# 0.000000  1
...
```

This is easy to compute on a small dataset. However, it's not efficient on a dataset with more than say 10000 rows. In my case my dataset has one million rows and I still need to calculate these scores for every data point in the dataset.  How can I speed up this process?

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(col1 = c(-0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, 2.39571919598653, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594, 
-0.417410794512594, -0.417410794512594), col2 = c(-0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, 3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, 3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, -0.256532467081718, 
-0.256532467081718, 3.89813836978099, -0.256532467081718), col3 = c(-0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 
1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, -0.836604889615016, 
-0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 
1.19530624962758, 1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758, 
1.19530624962758, -0.836604889615016, 1.19530624962758), col4 = c(-0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 
2.017797488074, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 2.017797488074, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, 
-0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795, -0.495589403265795), 
    col5 = c(-0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, 11.4217770449072, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, 11.4217770449072, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, -0.0875519675348337, 
    -0.0875519675348337), col6 = c(2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    2.18369082211692, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, 2.18369082211692, -0.457939852518312, 
    -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312, -0.457939852518312
    ), col7 = c(-0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    3.30548137598026, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 3.30548137598026, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 3.30548137598026, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, 3.30548137598026, 3.30548137598026, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, 3.30548137598026, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, 3.30548137598026, 3.30548137598026, -0.302527510907319, 
    3.30548137598026, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319, 
    -0.302527510907319, -0.302527510907319), col8 = c(-0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, 3.31585425791884, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, 
    -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003, -0.301581123669003
    ), col9 = c(-0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 3.25860440002273, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    3.25860440002273, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, -0.306879550343346, 
    -0.306879550343346), col10 = c(-0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 3.25560704686983, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    3.25560704686983, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 3.25560704686983, 
    3.25560704686983, 3.25560704686983, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, 3.25560704686983, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 3.25560704686983, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    3.25560704686983, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033, 
    -0.3071620864033, -0.3071620864033)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = "data.frame")
```